# UIDocumentPickerViewControllerが開かない

Tags: swift

Swiftでファイル選択画面のUIを表示したいと思っています。
UIDocumentPickerViewControllerというのを使えばそれらしきことが出来るのではないかと思い、私は以下の記事を参考にして、コードを作成しました。

UIDocumentPickerViewControllerで選択ファイルを絞る & iOS14からのUTType
https://qiita.com/mittsu/items/5e027f4cb62719abba72

以下のコードをiOS14で実行しましたが、ファイル選択の画面が表示されませんでした。
私のコードはどこが間違っていますか？

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

import UniformTypeIdentifiers
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func fileSelectButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *)
        {
            let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
                forOpeningContentTypes: [
                    UTType.mpeg4Audio,
                    UTType.mp3
                ],
                asCopy: true)
            picker.delegate = self
            self.navigationController?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
                documentTypes: [
                    String(kUTTypeMPEG4Audio),
                    String(kUTTypeMP3)
                ],
                in: .import)
            picker.delegate = self
            self.navigationController?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

        if let filePath = urls.first?.description {
            print("filepath:\(filePath)")
        }
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        print("cancel")
    }
}
```

XCodeから、Signing & Capabilitiesから、iCloudを追加し、Key-value storageをチェックしています。
また、Keychain Stringも追加しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

XCodeのバージョンはVersion 12.1 (12A7403)を使用しています。

Comment: `self.navigationController?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)`という行がありますが、あなたの`ViewController`は確実にnavigation controllerに埋め込まれているのでしょうか?

Comment: navigation controllerに埋め込まれていませんでした...。navigation controllerがないと動かないのですね。self.presentに直したら開きました。ご回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: コメントは回答欄ではありませんので、是非ご自身で「回答」してみてください。見つけられたような新機能紹介の記事では、紹介したい事柄以外の部分が大きく端折られていることが多いので、その辺をうまく考えて利用していってください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboad上などで、navigation controllerを使用していなかったため、`self.navigationController?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)`ではうまくいかなかったようです。

`self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)`に変更すると開くようになりました。

```
@IBAction func fileSelectButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *)
    {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
            forOpeningContentTypes: [
                UTType.mpeg4Audio,
                UTType.mp3
            ],
            asCopy: true)
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
            documentTypes: [
                String(kUTTypeMPEG4Audio),
                String(kUTTypeMP3)
            ],
            in: .import)
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```